# Loading data from json in Flask app

Tags: javascript, json, flask

I have a Flask app with the following structure:

```
/
    static
        script.js
        data.json
    templates
        index.html
    app.py
```

`app.py` renders the `index.html` template which includes the js as `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script.js">`.

The javascript file simply loads the json file using the path "data.json" as it is in the same directory. However, this always gives me a 404 not found error on the "data.json" file coming from the javascript. I was wondering if there is a correct way to access files from javascript when launched through Flask.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you used to load data.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get static file in this way:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}
```

See the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files) for more detail.

In `script.js`, you may need to load the `data.json` by `/static/data.json`.